# When Connected in WiFi if I connect the ethernet cable Ubuntu 19.10 doesn't switch to ethernet connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I noticed that if I'm connected to wifi and then I connect my desk ethernet cable, the connection keep to go through the lower speed wifi instead to switch to the Wired and faster connection as expected.
NOTE: both connections land on the same vlan/subnet.

Previous versions of Ubuntu behave like Windows, giving priority to wired connection over wifi when both connected.

I looked for some netplan/NetworkManager config but found nothing.

Do you noticed the same behavior?

Comment: No. On my 19.10 machines, Ubuntu automatically and correctly switches to the wired connection. Test your cable. Check your settings - the wired connection can be turned off in settings.

Comment: Before you plug in the cable, `sudo journalctl -f`. Then plug in the cable. `^C` and Read the messages. Also `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: It depends on the speeds of your LAN vs your WLAN. Do `sudo lshw -C network` and see what speed your LAN is connected. If it's not 1G, then the wireless may actually be the faster connection in your case.

Comment: Well actually I don't have the grasp on why this is happening :) I wasn't aware that I was using a 100Mb/s wired connection (test) so I switched to a 1Gb wired but the same the traffic is going through WiFi. So I did some test and now the behavior is changed. I mean if wired is up it has the priority over wifi. The message that wasn't present in previous test is "NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL". I'm going to investigate...

Comment: I did check the output of journalctl (nice command btw, thanks) and when the NetworkManager doesn't switch back to the wired connection it's missing the "manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL" statement. I can't find why. I'll investigate.